# Magento 2 Search Rest API

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, catalogsearch, search-criteria, rest-api

I need to change the response of Search Rest API in Magento 2.

**Request**:`rest/V1/search?searchCriteria[requestName]=quick_search_container
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=search_term
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=t-shirt
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][field]=sleeve_type
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][1][value]=173
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][2][field]=neck
&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][2][value]=105`

**Response**:

```
"items": [
    {
        "id": 154,
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "score",
                "value": "45.5335884094238300"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

need to add more product information like **product name, sku, type, images etc..**,

```
"items": [

    {
        "id": 154,
        "sku": "sample001",
        "name": "sample product 1",
        "type": "configurable",
        "image_url": "http://magentohost/pub/media/catalog/product/s/s/1.png",
        "custom_attributes": [
            {
                "attribute_code": "score",
                "value": "45.5335884094238300"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but response have id and score only. How to add product information to search api response?

Comment: user54334 did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For get the product information in the `Search API` you have to use `searchCriteria` with `filters` in request URL. Use below API Request URL.

**Request URL:**

```
http://localhost/magentosample230/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25Watch%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=%25Bag %25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=like
```

**Response:**

```
    {
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 36,
            "sku": "24-MG04",
            "name": "Aim Analog Watch",
            "attribute_set_id": 11,
            "price": 45,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:59",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:59",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "6"
                    }
                ],
                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 36,
                    "product_id": 36,
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
            },
            "product_links": [],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 41,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/g/mg04-bk-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg04-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg04-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg04-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "aim-analog-watch"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "3",
                        "6"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>Stay light-years ahead of the competition with our Aim Analog Watch. The flexible, rubberized strap is contoured to conform to the shape of your wrist for a comfortable all-day fit. The face features three illuminated hands, a digital read-out of the current time, and stopwatch functions.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Japanese quartz movement.</li>\n<li>Strap fits 7\" to 8.0\".</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "9,17,5,11"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "material",
                    "value": "44,45"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gender",
                    "value": "80"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_gear",
                    "value": "86,87,90"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 37,
            "sku": "24-MG01",
            "name": "Endurance Watch",
            "attribute_set_id": 11,
            "price": 49,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:59",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:59",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "6"
                    }
                ],
                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 37,
                    "product_id": 37,
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
            },
            "product_links": [],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 42,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/g/mg01-bk-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg01-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg01-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg01-bk-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "endurance-watch"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "3",
                        "6"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>It's easy to track and monitor your training progress with the Endurance Watch. You'll see standard info like time, date and day of the week, but it also functions for the serious high-mileage athete: lap counter, stopwatch, distance, heart rate, speed/pace, cadence and altitude.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Digital display.</li>\n<li>LED backlight.</li>\n<li>Strap fits 7\" to 10\".</li>\n<li>1-year limited warranty.</li>\n<li>Comes with polished metal case.</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "9,16"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "material",
                    "value": "43,45,48"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gender",
                    "value": "80"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_gear",
                    "value": "86,87,90"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 38,
            "sku": "24-MG03",
            "name": "Summit Watch",
            "attribute_set_id": 11,
            "price": 54,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:15:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:15:00",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "8"
                    }
                ],
                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 38,
                    "product_id": 38,
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
            },
            "product_links": [],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 43,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/g/mg03-br-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg03-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg03-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg03-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "summit-watch"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "3",
                        "7",
                        "6",
                        "8"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>Trek high and low in the attractive Summit Watch, which features a digital LED display with time and date, stopwatch, lap counter, and 3-second backlight. It can also calculate the number of steps taken and calories burned.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Brushed metal case.</li>\n<li>Water resistant (100 meters).</li>\n<li>Buckle clasp.</li>\n<li>Strap fits 7\" - 10\".</li>\n<li>1-year limited warranty.</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "9,16,17,5,11"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "material",
                    "value": "43,44,48"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gender",
                    "value": "80,81,84"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_gear",
                    "value": "86,87,90"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "new",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 39,
            "sku": "24-MG05",
            "name": "Cruise Dual Analog Watch",
            "attribute_set_id": 11,
            "price": 55,
            "status": 1,
            "visibility": 4,
            "type_id": "simple",
            "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:15:00",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-30 07:15:00",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "website_ids": [
                    1
                ],
                "category_links": [
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "3"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "7"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "6"
                    },
                    {
                        "position": 0,
                        "category_id": "8"
                    }
                ],
                "stock_item": {
                    "item_id": 39,
                    "product_id": 39,
                    "stock_id": 1,
                    "qty": 100,
                    "is_in_stock": true,
                    "is_qty_decimal": false,
                    "show_default_notification_message": false,
                    "use_config_min_qty": true,
                    "min_qty": 0,
                    "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "min_sale_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
                    "max_sale_qty": 10000,
                    "use_config_backorders": true,
                    "backorders": 0,
                    "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
                    "notify_stock_qty": 1,
                    "use_config_qty_increments": true,
                    "qty_increments": 0,
                    "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
                    "enable_qty_increments": false,
                    "use_config_manage_stock": true,
                    "manage_stock": true,
                    "low_stock_date": null,
                    "is_decimal_divided": false,
                    "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
                }
            },
            "product_links": [],
            "options": [],
            "media_gallery_entries": [
                {
                    "id": 44,
                    "media_type": "image",
                    "label": "Image",
                    "position": 1,
                    "disabled": false,
                    "types": [
                        "image",
                        "small_image",
                        "thumbnail"
                    ],
                    "file": "/m/g/mg05-br-0.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "tier_prices": [],
            "custom_attributes": [
                {
                    "attribute_code": "image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg05-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "small_image",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg05-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
                    "value": "/m/g/mg05-br-0.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "options_container",
                    "value": "container2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "url_key",
                    "value": "cruise-dual-analog-watch"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "required_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "has_options",
                    "value": "0"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_ids",
                    "value": [
                        "3",
                        "7",
                        "6",
                        "8"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "description",
                    "value": "<p>Whether you're traveling or wish you were, you'll never let time zones perplex you again with the Cruise Dual Analog Watch. The thick, adjustable band promises a comfortable, personalized fit to this classy, modern time piece.</p>\n<ul>\n<li>Two dials.</li>\n<li>Stainless steel case.</li>\n<li>Adjustable leather band.</li>\n</ul>"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "activity",
                    "value": "9"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "material",
                    "value": "35,44"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "gender",
                    "value": "80"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "category_gear",
                    "value": "86,88,90"
                },
                {
                    "attribute_code": "new",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "search_criteria": {
        "filter_groups": [
            {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "field": "name",
                        "value": "%Watch%",
                        "condition_type": "like"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "total_count": 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this question [Magento2 Rest Api Search Criteria not working properly!](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172767/magento2-rest-api-search-criteria-not-working-properly)
you can add a "fields" parameter...

Not used it, but from the answer I guess it works...

**EDIT:**
Actually, from what I can tell, "fields" is used for restricting the data returned, not adding more data.

Answer (score 0):

The beautiful thing about Magento is that you can take reference from the its core code. For answering the question I will took the example of the product API call to filter product from the "color" attribute code.

`rest/all/V1/products-render-info?
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=color&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=53&
searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=size&
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=asc&
storeId=1
&currencyCode=usd`

From your code I assume that this is custom search criteria. Try to build search criteria in this way and if you are using the Magento code this can be helpful to you.